# Why doesn't rootMargin of IntersectionObserver seem to be respected when evaluating a sticky element?

Tags: javascript, css

Looking at the [IntersectionObserver  API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin), it sounds like you can use `rootMargin` to specify offsets for the container to coerce the API to fire when an element is either near or some number of pixels inside a target container. But with the below example, it seems to not fire. I've set the 'rootMargin' to have an 11px top margin, so the sticky element (which sticks 10px from the top) *should* be partially overlapping, thus causing the observer to report a change in visibility.

This logic works fine if I have `top: -1px` instead of `top: 10px`, but from all the documentation I can find, this should work as well. I've tried a few variations of margins, negative values, etc to try to make this work, without success, but randomly guessing shouldn't be the solution.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="before-content">This content should scroll off the screen</div>
 <div class="sticky">Sticky content</div>
 <div class="after-content">This is some extra content after</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  color: #b58900;
}

.container {
  background-color: #002b36;
}

.before-content {
  height: 50px;
}

.sticky {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #073642;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.after-content {
  height: 200px;
}
```

JS:

```
const sticky = document.getElementsByClassName("sticky")[0];

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  ([e]) => {
    console.log(e.intersectionRatio)
    const stuck = e.intersectionRatio < 1.0;
    sticky.innerHTML  = "Sticky content (" + String(stuck) + ")"
  }, {
    threshold: [1],
    // This doesn't work; changing the css ".sticky { top : -1 }" does cause the intersect logic
    // to fire and "stuck == true", but according to mdn docs it sounds like setting rootMargin
    // this way should have the same effect.
    rootMargin: '11px 0px 0px 0px',
  }
)


observer.observe(sticky)
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kyfvxLea/28/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I managed to get it to fix here.

```js
const sticky = document.getElementsByClassName("sticky")[0];

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  ([e]) => {
    const stuck =  e.isIntersecting;
    sticky.innerHTML  = "Sticky content (" + String(stuck) + ")"
  }, {
    threshold: [1],
    // This doesn't work; changing the css ".sticky { top : -1 }" does cause the intersect logic
    // to fire and "stuck == true", but according to mdn docs it sounds like setting rootMargin
    root: document,
    // this way should have the same effect.
    rootMargin: '-11px 0px 0px 0px',
  }
)


observer.observe(sticky)
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #002b36;
}

* {
  color: #b58900;
}
.before-content {
  height: 50px;
}

.sticky {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #073642;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.after-content {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="before-content">This content should scroll off the screen</div>
 <div class="sticky">Sticky content</div>
 <div class="after-content">This is some extra content afterThis is some extra content afterThis is some extra content afterThis is some extra content afterThis is some extra content afterThiThis is some extra content afters is some extra content afterThis is some extra content afterThis is some extra content afterThis is some extra content after</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Glidias/vzLaxeq1/4/

2 things I realised which appears that the the mdn docs isn't  very clear at times and can be rather misleading:

- In order for rootMargin to work, root parameter must be specified as well even if it's meant for the default. (ie. the owning "document")
- The "-1" top trick is actually minus 1 off the **magnitude** of the top (only) margin offset, but the top margin offset should be negative as well, indicating the "border-like" offset of the container, (not actually the actual css margin positioning). As described, "which contains offsets for one or more sides of the root's bounding box"

Comment: Thank for pointing out that you need to explicitly add `root:document`. That's the only piece of magic I needed :)